# phone number validation with specific requirements

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to create a phone number validation but with some specific requirements .not accepting more than 10  max numbers and  not accepting more than 20 characters if it has special characters (numbers|space|.|+|(|)|-|/|X/).whats the best approach to dot this with regex

i tried this but /^(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3}-(?!00)\d{2}-(?!0{4})\d{4}$/ but not getting the expecting result

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/9Vs9TC/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be asserting that there are not 21 characters present in the string using a negative lookahead `^(?!.{21}$)`

Then match 10 times a single digit with optional characters that you consider special on the left and right using `[() .+|\/-]*`

```
^(?!.{21}$)[() .+|\/-]*(?:\d[() .+|\/-]*){10}[() .+|\/-]*$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Vs9TC/1r).